# How to check across columns for value appearing certain number of times?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

What is the best way to check if a value appears more than a certain number of times across multiple columns?

I have this in the column: `=COUNTIF(A2:D2,"Adv")>1`, will this work to check if the value occurs more than once across columns A-D?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FYY00QTGaz0bituGKOjqqlI1MyHcOr8NlcPiEHlMDg8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have any idea why the same formula would not be working on "sheet 2", Line 3, Column U ?  It is the same forumla but is not catching the TRUE value in range.

Comment: The formula works on the first sheet, but it fails to work on Line 3 Column U of the second sheet. I am not sure why.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the TRUE and FALSE in the formula in those columns.

Comment: I added another tab with another column having the same issue. Column Q on Sheet 3 should catch if the value "Adv" occurs one or more times in columns K-L, but it does not work. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: do not use `""` around anything but text.  Numbers and Booleans do not get them.  You have `""` around numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=(COUNTIF(K1:L1, "Adv")>0)*(M1="Adv")*(O1>=20)*(P1>=9)=1
```

[image]